# Auto page down / scrolling after a few seconds using more, less, or something similar

Tags: terminal, less, pager, more

When using `more` or `less`, the output is paused at the end of each page.
Is there some way to have it pause only for a few seconds (configurable or not), and then continue to the next page? Is there some other tool that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember playing with something like that in the MS-DOS age. Cute, but very unpractical.

But just as an exercise in strange things:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read 
do
    echo "$REPLY"
    sleep 1s
done
```

Save it as 'scroll' and use `scroll < textfile`

If you want to do a page-by-page scroll, you can use `tput` to determine how many rows there is in a terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read 
do
    lines=`tput lines`
    while [ $lines -gt 0 ]
    do
        echo "$REPLY"
        read
        lines=$(( $lines - 1 ))
    done
    sleep 1s
done
```

Comment: Would there be a way to sleep only after filling the terminal's height?

Comment: Sure, just get a number of lines on the terminal - `tput lines`. And print that much lines before sleep.

Comment: Would you edit your answer with `tput` so I could accept it? :)